# UIAlertView brings up completely unexpected function

Tags: iphone

```
    -(void) buttonClick:(id) sender
{

    action=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Confirm for action" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [action addButtonWithTitle:@"Yes"];


    [action show];
    [action release];



}

    - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)action didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        [self func1];
    }
    else if (buttonIndex ==0)  //cancel
    {

    }
}
```

instead of executing func1 when clicked Yes on alertview, the app pop up a registration form from my registration page in the app.

Answer (score 0):

set a break point on "if (buttonIndex == 1) " and follow the code using step into button. the problem should be somewhere else in your program.

Comment: I step through it. Func1 executed at background when clicked yes on alertview  while registration form popped up uninvited.  I use the same logic at another section of the code and it has no problem.

Comment: ok do one more thing set a tag to alert view and and check this tag in its delegate method. to make sure that it is the alert on which you are pressing the yes button